# WSL (windows subsystem linux) breaks $PATH when the windows PATH has folder names with spaces

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I start WSL I cant add folders to path. I found out that this is because folders that are included in the windows PATH that has white spaces in their name break the linux $PATH.
:
For instance, when putting $PATH in the command line I am getting 
....Some other folders...:/mnt/c/Program: no such file or directory.

If this was a manual process, I would use either "Program Files" of Program\ files but this is imported before ~/.bashrc kicks in so I dont know how to fix this.

Thank you for helping

Comment: I get this exact behavior only after updating docker today.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem when I created a second instance of Ubuntu 20.04 and set the default user through /etc/wsl.conf. Quoting $PATH in Line 6 ( export PATH=$PATH:${snap_bin_path} ) in /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh solved the problem for me.

Comment: What is ${snap_bin_path}? Never heard of it, must be related to Snap.How can I import the windows path to bash?

Answer (score 2):

Disable windows interop:

```
PATH=/usr/bin sudo su
echo -e "[interop]\nenabled=false\nappendWindowsPath=false" >> /etc/wsl.conf
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#interop-settings

Answer (score 1):

Folders with spaces in their names should be enclosed with "", '', or escaped with backslash.

This is my path in .bashrc which I added in WSL to be able to use the `code .` to start up VSCode from WSL.

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/Kamal/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"
```

Comment: Thank you Kamal Hakim.

I know how to keep folder names with white spces intact. But my problem is different, These are folders the WSL adds automatically. The windows environmental variable named PATH is transferred to WSL linux as $PATH but since it contains folder names with white apces it breaks.